# How can I apply the Homomorphic filtering in Python (i.e. using OpenCV)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I have to process a **numpy** frame using the **Homomorphic filtering** to obtain the image for **FisherFaces**, improving the recognition. I need the equivalent Homomorphic filtering in **Python** language. I've tried to search some functions in **OpenCV (v2.4)** without finding the solution.

I have also seen this (and many other links):
[Homomorphic filtering in Cplusplus language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740934/opencv-homomorphic-filter).
But it hasn't solved my problem.

I hope you'll can help me. *Thank you a lot*.

Comment: If you have to implement it in Python, do you really need an implementation with OpenCV or `scipy` implementation would work too?

Comment: It doesn't matter how to implement the filtering. Scipy can be a suitable possibility.

Comment: If so, then _Possible duplicate_ [Segmenting License Plate Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters)